# custom query pagination worpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm pretty new to wordpress. My custom query pagination not working properly, it arrives until page 17 than stops working (i have 21 pages of products).

I have tried to change it with pre get posts function but it doesn't work as expected. what could be the issue and what i can try?

```
<?php
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $term = get_queried_object();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'paged'          => $paged,
        );

        if ($term instanceof WP_Term && 'product_cat' === $term->taxonomy) {
            $taxonomy_slug = $term->slug;
        
            // Custom query to get products from the current taxonomy.
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => 12,
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'tax_query'      => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $taxonomy_slug,
                    ),
                ),
            );
        }
        

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'category') !== false) {
            // Filter categories based on the visible products
            $object_ids = $query->posts ? wp_list_pluck($query->posts, 'ID') : array();
        } else {
            // No filtering, include all products
            $object_ids = array();
        }

        $product_categories = get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => true, // Exclude empty categories
            'object_ids' => $query->posts ? wp_list_pluck($query->posts, 'ID') : array(),

        ));
    ?>

<div class="pagination">
            <?php
            $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
            
            echo paginate_links( array(
                'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
                'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                'total' => $query->max_num_pages
            ) ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more about how you are noticing the problem? Specifically, does the pagination kick out the links as you expect, but when you click them they don't have the correct data? Or is it that the links themselves aren't correct?

Comment: Yes, when I click the pagination links at the bottom, they are working until page 17, after that page if i click the links they give me 404. The Strange thing is if I type in paginate link -> total the wp_query -> max_num_pages it will give me 17 Pages, but in the custom query there are 21 (with the ones after 17 not working)

Comment: Do the bad links look correct? Like `https://example.com/thing/?paged=20`?

Comment: When you view page 17 of the results, compare the last product you see there to the last product in the list of products you see in the Dashboard, just to confirm that page 17 is in fact an intermediate page of results and not the final one.  If it's the final one, then perhaps $query->max_num_pages is behaving as if posts_per_page is 10 and not 12.  Could WP be using a cached value for max_num_pages?

Comment: _"The Strange thing is if I type in paginate link -> total the wp_query -> max_num_pages it will give me 17 Pages, but in the custom query there are 21 (with the ones after 17 not working)"_ - sounds like you still have the main query, and your custom query, interfering with each other. Resp. like you rather _should_ have manipulated the main query, instead of making your own, custom one? Can you give some more details here, "where" exactly you are - are you trying to paginate through posts on an archive page, did you create your own listing of something, or what exactly is this?

Comment: Yes, it is the archive page of a woocommerce costum archive page, in archive-product.php, so i try to show all the products and paginate them. I would like to do that with the custom query, because i created a filtring system

Comment: How many products are there in all?